# Chart boost sdk for android

Tags: unity-game-engine, chartboost

I am trying to use Chartboost sdk for unity game.When I try to showInterstial.I have even tried caching it. But didLoadInterstitial callback gives the error code 6.The log showed me this.

> E/CBJSON  (30245): error creating new json object
>           E/CBJSON  (30245): org.json.JSONException: Value v2 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:159)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:172)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Libraries.e$a.k(SourceFile:495)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.c.D(SourceFile:744)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.c.A(SourceFile:718)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.impl.ad.e(SourceFile:147)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.e.c(SourceFile:170)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.e.b(SourceFile:125)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost$7.run(SourceFile:815)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost.a(SourceFile:1394)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(SourceFile:820)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.chartboost.sdk.unity.CBPlugin$5.run(CBPlugin.java:141)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>           E/CBJSON  (30245):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Also I have got the log saying this:

> V/CBRequestManager(30245): Request /interstitial/get succeeded.
>   Response code: 200, body: {
>           V/CBRequestManager(30245):     "message": "No publisher campaigns found",
>           V/CBRequestManager(30245):     "status": 404
>           }

Please help.

Comment: have you resolved this? i also set up chartboost dashbored properly and facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't create a [Publishing Campaign](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/sections/201082359-Publishing-Campaigns) for your Chartboost Application. Go to your [Chartboost Dashboard](https://dashboard.chartboost.com/) and [Create a new Publishing Campaign](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/204930539-Creating-a-Publishing-Campaign).

Comment: I am actually trying with the test app. Publishing campaign is required only if we are releasing the build right?

Comment: You have to create campaign in any way. Read [this](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201121969-Why-can-t-I-see-ads-in-my-app-).